# Rails select with suggestions and remote data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have, for example, project and category models:

```
# project.rb
has_and_belongs_to_many :categories

# category.rb
has_and_belongs_to_many :projects
```

In the front-end I need to:

- Show input for name of the project category
- Suggest / autocomplete category by name if it exist
- If it doesn't exists, I need to
  dynamically create it and paste name into input and hold ID, then
  send ID to server when user submits form.

So, I have categories controller, which have methods **search** and **create**. Search returns in JSON format pairs of ID and NAME of suggested categories; create saves category into database and returns pair of ID and NAME when user submits new category into input.
It is about *multiple* category input.

Also, in other part of website we could meet models, that uses category model not as has_and_belongs_to, but as belongs_to. There I need to show select box with *single* value of category, but with the same logic with multiple input.

Select2 or selectize libs covers most part of my issue, but I have no idea how to hold IDs instead of names into input and how to render name of category into input and send ID when user submits form.

Are there any libs or technics to solve this issue?

Comment: http://railscasts.com/episodes/258-token-fields

Comment: What is your question? Having a hard time following what you've done so far and what you still need.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend watching Ryan Bates' excellent [RailsCasts episode](http://railscasts.com/episodes/258-token-fields-revised) on this. He demonstrates the `find_or_create` type of functionality you're describing, but using the jQuery Tokeninput library.

If you're committed to using select2, you can use a similar approach as Ryan's on the back-end, while using the [Tagging support](https://select2.github.io/examples.html#tags) in select2.

Comment: I've watched casts you referred more than 2 years ago. It do not cover my issue.

Answer (score 1):

If I were you I'd used model ProjectCategoryBeloning, that will be "between" Project and Category: has_many instead of has_many_and_belongs_to. To link Project to Category, I would use nested attributes on the ui in the form of the project. For autocompletion of the categories there is a good jquery.ui: https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/ that you can use with AJAX.